# In Hive, how do I find the number of differences between 2 columns?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm trying to find the number of differences when comparing two columns.
For example:

Column 1: 'ABCDEFGH!'
Column 2: 'aBcDSfGh?'

Number of differences is 6.

How can I achieve such thing in Hive?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) function

```
select levenshtein(column1, column2) from table
```

Comment: `select levenshtein('ABCDEFGH!', 'aBcDSfGh?');` worked